# WIll money that a friend sent me (for his share of dinner bill that I paid) be taxed in India?

Tags: income-tax, india, gift-tax

I paid for dinner with 3 of my friends.

And at the end of the day, these 3 people send me Rs.500 each.
They sent me the money via UPI bank transfer (say, using phonePe or BHIM).

Will this amount (Rs. 1500) be taxed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this amount is not taxable. For it to be taxable it should be more than ₹ 50,000 in a financial year.

Even then if you can establish that the transfer of funds was not a gift and more of convenience, there is no tax applicable.

Comment: More than ₹ 50,000 in one transaction?
Or is it like the sum of amounts that I receive from my friends in a financial year should be less than ₹ 50,000 to avoid tax?

Comment: Sum of all in one financial year

Comment: Is the 1500 and the 50000 the same unit of money? i.e. 30 such lunches and he’d be close? Or is there a decimal point like the 1500 was more like $15, vs $50K?

Comment: How can I prove that this is for convenience? What is the procedure for it?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the reasons provided by Dheer, the amount is not taxable for other reasons.

Most importantly the payment is not income to you. It's payment to a restaurant for a dinner,  a payment that happens to have been paid through you.  You might consider yourself the (unpaid) agent handling the transaction for him, or you might consider it a very short term interest free loan.  Neither are going to attract tax.

Secondly the tax office is not interested in amounts as low as a single dinner. That's not a legal reason but a very practical reason. If it was a larger amount the tax office might require you to document the transaction and explain why you were processing it for your friend. But for an amount as low as a dinner they are simply not going to care.